# Elasticsearch highlighting on ngram filter is weird if min_gram is set to 1

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have this index

```
{
  "settings":{
    "index":{
      "number_of_replicas":0,
      "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
          "default":{
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer":"keyword",
            "filter":[
              "lowercase",
              "my_ngram"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter":{
          "my_ngram":{
            "type":"nGram",
            "min_gram":2,
            "max_gram":20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm performing this search through the tire gem

```
{
   "query":{
      "query_string":{
         "query":"xyz",
         "default_operator":"AND"
      }
   },
   "sort":[
      {
         "count":"desc"
      }
   ],
   "filter":{
      "term":{
         "active":true,
         "_type":null
      }
   },
   "highlight":{
      "fields":{
         "name":{

         }
      },
      "pre_tags":[
         "<strong>"
      ],
      "post_tags":[
         "</strong>"
      ]
   }
}
```

and I have two posts that should match named 'xyz post' and 'xyz question'
When I perform this search, I get the highlighted fields back properly

```
<strong>xyz</strong> question
<strong>xyz</strong> post
```

Now here's the thing ... as soon as I change min_gram to 1 in my index and reindex. the highlighted fields start coming back as this

```
<strong>x</strong><strong>y</strong><strong>z</strong> pos<strong>xyz</strong>t
<strong>x</strong><strong>y</strong><strong>z</strong> questio<strong>xyz</strong>n
```

I simply cannot understand why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Short Answer

You need to check your **mapping** and see if you use `fast-vector-highlighter`. But still you need to be quite careful about your queries.

### Detailed Answer

Assume using fresh instance of ES `0.20.4` on `localhost`.

Building on top of your example, let's add explicit mappings. Note I setup two different analysis for the `code` field. The only difference is `"term_vector":"with_positions_offsets"`.

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/myindex -d '
{
  "settings" : {
    "index":{
      "number_of_replicas":0,
      "number_of_shards":1,
      "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
          "default":{
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer":"keyword",
            "filter":[
              "lowercase",
              "my_ngram"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter":{
          "my_ngram":{
            "type":"nGram",
            "min_gram":1,
            "max_gram":20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "product" : {
      "properties" : {
        "code" : {
          "type" : "multi_field",
          "fields" : {
            "code" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "analyzer" : "default",
              "store" : "yes"
            },
            "code.ngram" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "analyzer" : "default",
              "store" : "yes",
              "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Index some data.

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/myindex/product' -d '{
  "code" : "Samsung Galaxy i7500"
}'

curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/myindex/product' -d '{
  "code" : "Samsung Galaxy 5 Europa"
}'

curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/myindex/product' -d '{
  "code" : "Samsung Galaxy Mini"
}'
```

And now we can run queries.

#### 1) Search for 'i' to see one character search works with highlighting

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/myindex/product/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "fields" : [ "code" ],
  "query" : {
    "term" : {
      "code" : "i"
    }
  },
  "highlight" : {
    "number_of_fragments" : 0,
    "fields" : {
      "code":{},
      "code.ngram":{}
    }
  }
}'
```

This yields two search hits:

```
# 1
...
"fields" : {
  "code" : "Samsung Galaxy Mini"
},
"highlight" : {
  "code.ngram" : [ "Samsung Galaxy M<em>i</em>n<em>i</em>" ],
  "code" : [ "Samsung Galaxy M<em>i</em>n<em>i</em>" ]
}
# 2
...
"fields" : {
  "code" : "Samsung Galaxy i7500"
},
"highlight" : {
  "code.ngram" : [ "Samsung Galaxy <em>i</em>7500" ],
  "code" : [ "Samsung Galaxy <em>i</em>7500" ]
}
```

Both the `code` and `code.ngem` fields were correctly highlighted this time. But things change quickly when longer query is used:

#### 2) Search for 'y m'

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/myindex/product/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "fields" : [ "code" ],
  "query" : {
    "term" : {
      "code" : "y m"
    }
  },
  "highlight" : {
    "number_of_fragments" : 0,
    "fields" : {
      "code":{},
      "code.ngram":{}
    }
  }
}'
```

This yields:

```
"fields" : {
  "code" : "Samsung Galaxy Mini"
},
"highlight" : {
  "code.ngram" : [ "Samsung Galax<em>y M</em>ini" ],
  "code" : [ "Samsung Galaxy Min<em>y M</em>i" ]
}
```

The `code` fields is not highlighted correctly (similar to your case).

One important thing is that **term query** is used instead of **query_string**.

Comment: You are awesome my man, adding the term_vector fixed it! I wonder why the plain highlighter exhibits this strange behavior though?